# Accessing selected range address and cell values in Excel add in

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, office-interop

I'm endeavoring to write an Excel 2010 application add-in using .NET 4 and VS 2010.  What's proving difficult is accessing the range of cells selected by the user.  The user will select a series of n consecutive cells and then click a button on the ribbon bar.  Then after this button is clicked I need to access both the cell addresses for the range and also the cell values.  Below is my code.  get_Range is the closest method I've been able to find to what I need.  However, this method requires the first and last cell address.  Is there a similar method to this that will take the user-selected input range as a parameter? Also, after accessing the selected range I need to take the values contained in that range and to write them to a database.  I'm envisioning using something like range.SelectedValues that I would cast into a data table.  What is the correct way to access the set of selected values?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.  I'm lost in the PIA documentation and struggling to accomplish what should be a simple task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddIn2
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GetRageValues()
        {

            Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.get_Range("A1", "A3");

            //to be replaced with database insert
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You Selected" + range.Address);
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            GetRageValues();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In VBA the object you want is `Selection`,  The type of this object will vay depending on what is selected, if it's a range then it will be of type `Range`. I'm not sure what the equivalent is in `Interop` but it should be similar

Comment: Thanks.  The following is working for accessing the range "Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;".  What is the VBA equivalent for accessing the cell values in the range?

Comment: After tinkering further I was able to figure this out by accessing the Value2 property in the Cells object.  @Chris do you want to submit your comment as an answer so that I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA the object you want is `Selection`, The type of this object will vary depending on what is selected, if it's a range then it will be of type `Range`. I'm not sure what the equivalent is in Interop but it should be similar.

(Moved comment to Answer)

Answer (score 0):

For a .net Add-In project for Excel:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SelectedRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
```